# Are immunosuppressors necessary after a bone marrow transplant for Bubble Boy Syndrome?

Tags: immune-system, transplantation

I know that under normal circumstances, immunosuppressors are needed to mitigate the host body's immune reaction to the graft. However, people suffering Bubble Boy Syndrome have pretty much no immune system to begin with. Graft versus host disease does occur in some cases, but not all. So, in these other cases, are immunosupressors required?

Thanks to all!